# Create a measure depending on a filter

Tags: filter, powerbi, measure

I have two measures:

```
% PARTIC_REC_CORR = 
IF(
    SUM('RECEITA _SERVIÇO'[REC_CORRENTES])=0,
    "_",
    DIVIDE(
        SUM(BD_RH[PESSOAL + ENCARGOS + BENEFÍCIOS]),
        SUM('RECEITA _SERVIÇO'[REC_CORRENTES])
    )
)

% PARTIC_REC_CORR TOTAL = 
IF(
    SUM('REC_CORRENTES_1'[RECEITAS CORRENTES])=0,
    "_",
    DIVIDE(
        SUM(BD_RH[PESSOAL + ENCARGOS + BENEFÍCIOS]),
        SUM('REC_CORRENTES_1'[RECEITAS CORRENTES])
    )
)
```

Now I want to create a new one depending on the selected filter (dLocal).

[image: dLocal]

If nothing is selected, I want `% PARTIC_REC_CORR TOTAL`, otherwise `% PARTIC_REC_CORR`. I tried

```
% PARTIC_REC_CORR 2 = 
IF(
    ALL('dLocal'[SIESTADO]), 
    RH_INDICADORES[% PARTIC_REC_CORR TOTAL], 
    RH_INDICADORES[% PARTIC_REC_CORR]
)
```

unsuccessfully.

**dLocal**

```
SISESTADO CDESTADO
AC        24
AL        02
...       ...
```

**RECEITA _SERVIÇO**

```
DATA_BASE  CDESTADO REC_CORRENTES SISTESTADO
31/12/2018 24       99999,99      AC
31/12/2018 02       99999,99      AL
...        ...      ...           ...
31/12/2019 24       99999,99      AC
31/12/2019 02       99999,99      AL
...        ...      ...           ...
```

**REC_CORRENTES_1**

```
DATA_BASE  REC_CORRENTES
31/12/2018 99999999,99
31/12/2018 99999999,99
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

*Edit: the measures where in the wrong order*

```
% PARTIC_REC_CORR 2 = 
IF(
    ISFILTERED('dLocal'[SIESTADO])
    ,RH_INDICADORES[% PARTIC_REC_CORR]
    ,RH_INDICADORES[% PARTIC_REC_CORR TOTAL]
)
```

note that ISFILTERED considers only direct filter on a field.

Your formula is not working because ALL() returns a whole column with all the values (ALL removes the filters), how that is considered inside the IF "check expression" I have no idea.

Comment: `ISFILTERED` doesn't work because I have a SISESTADO filter on the page

Comment: In my answer I had the two formulas swapped. What do you mean with ISFILTERED doesn't work? just create a measure test = ISFILTERED('table'[column]) and check if it returns true or false